# Who knows what's wrong with my ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have this $.ajax method call:

```
var w_command = "add_holiday"
var w_type = "POST"
var w_id = "123321"

$.ajax(
    {
    type: w_type,
    url: w_command,
    parameters: 
        {
        to_find_id: w_id
        },
    success:function()
        {
        //Do something on success      
        alert('done');
        }
    });
```

which calls this method from a controller:

```
def add_holiday
    RHoliday.create(holiday_id: params[:to_find_id].to_s, group_id: @group.id.to_s)
end
```

I also get the `alert('done');` which tells me, that the AJAX request works, and finds the method. 
So why does it still not create anything?

EDIT:

```
Started POST "/groups/133978052/add_holiday" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-03 12:58:54 +0200
Processing by GroupsController#add_holiday as */*
Parameters: {"to_find_id"=>"4", "group_id"=>"133978052"}
←[1m←[36mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", 99119911]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
```

Comment: From ajax it calls `add_holiday` and you expect it would call `add_timespan`?

Comment: Oh... sorry... mixed up my controllers a little... add_timespan is handled with a very similar script.

Comment: So then, you should see something in `development.log` on the server when it calls this method.

Comment: I'm have my Console opened. It even shows me some amazing stuff. I'll post it as an edit!

Comment: Well, there are a lot of variations of what happened there. I could say, for example, it redirects this call to root route because it didn't found a valid user.

Comment: But wouldn't it then kick me, before I can access the Method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing called `parameters`, it's `data`

```
$.ajax({
    type : w_type,
    url  : w_command,
    data : {
        to_find_id: w_id
    },
    success:function()  {
        //Do something on success      
        alert('done');
    }
});
```

Comment: ok... and what is with params[to_find_id]? does this have to be changed too?

Comment: Don't know, I'm not that into RoR, but I was under the impression you'd use `request.post` to get post data ?